# find out the object id of an array[x] if you know the array[x]->ID?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, object, pdo

Let's say that we have this array for example from a previews question... How can i find the **[X]=> stdClass Object** if we know that the [id] of this object is [id] => 9???

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 8
            [book_category] => C Program
            [book_id] => 2
            [book_name] => C Language
            [book_category_id] => 8
            [book_in_stock] => 5
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 8
            [book_category] => C Program
            [book_id] => 1
            [book_name] => C++
            [book_category_id] => 8
            [book_in_stock] => 10
        )

    [X] => stdClass Object
        (
            **[id] => 9**
            [book_category] => English
            [book_id] => 3
            [book_name] => Comp Eng
            [book_category_id] => 9
            [book_in_stock] => 5
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 9
            [book_category] => English
            [book_id] => 4
            [book_name] => Eng English
            [book_category_id] => 9
            [book_in_stock] => 5
        )

)
```

Comment: thanks guys in advance!!! It's driving me crazy you know!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On PHP 7:

```
$key = array_search( 9, array_column( $array, 'id' ) );
```

On PHP < 7 see other answers, or — if you want emulate `array_column`:

```
function array_column2( $array, $column )
{
    return array_map
    ( 
        function( $row ) use( $column )
        {
            return is_object( $row ) ? $row->$column : $row[$column];
        }
        , $array
    );
}

$key = array_search( 9, array_column2( $array, 'id' ) );
```

<kbd>**[3v4l.org demo](https://3v4l.org/ss0JA)**</kbd>

---

- Read more about [array_column()](http://php.net/array_column)
- Read more about [array_map()](http://php.net/array_map)

Comment: it works also!! i'll accept your solution as best because now i have php5 installed but you gave also a solution to php7!! thanks a lot !!!!

Answer (score 1):

Or use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-filter.php):

```
$result=array_filter($array, function($x) {
    return $x->id == 9;
});
```

Will return all objects with id 9. If id is unique you can access the object with `$result[0]`.

Comment: i used your solution and it works but i cant access the object with $result[0]. i access it with $result['value_array']!!

Comment: and now im stuck with it because the whole point was to get the value from a dropdown list and input it to extract the name of the book for example. but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You have to take the long way around and search every element of the array:

```
foreach( $array as $key => $array_element ) {
    if( $array_element-> id == 9 ) {
        // Do what you want here. The value you're looking for is in $key.
    }
}
```